# TypeError: Cannot read property 'change' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

Why does this error occur in the following code? I have already imported 'Simulate' from 'react-testing-library' but the error states that 'Simulate' is 'undefined'

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, Simulate } from 'react-testing-library';
import CommentFeed from './CommentFeed';

const createProps = props => ({
header: 'Comment Feed',
comments: [
   {
      author: 'Ian Wilson',
      text: 'A boats a boat but a mystery box could be anything.',
   },
   {
     author: 'Max Powers Jr',
     text: 'Krypton sucks.',
   },
  ],
  createComment: jest.fn(),
  ...props,
})

describe('CommentFeed', () => {
  const props = { header : 'Comment Feed', comments : []};

  /* ... */

  it('allows the user to add a comment', () => {
    // Arrange
    const newComment = { author: 'Socrates', text: 'Why?' };
    let props = createProps();
    const { container, getByLabelText } = render(<CommentFeed {...props} />);

    const authorNode = getByLabelText('Author');
    const textNode = getByLabelText('Comment');
    const formNode = container.querySelector('form');

   // Act
    authorNode.value = newComment.author;
    textNode.value = newComment.text;

    Simulate.change(authorNode); // Where the error occurs
    Simulate.change(textNode);

    Simulate.submit(formNode);

    // Assert
    expect(props.createComment).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(props.createComment).toHaveBeenCalledWith(newComment);
  });
});
```

I was searching for this issue but couldn't find any information about 'Simulate' behavior

Comment: Welcome to SO! I couldn't find any reference to `Simulate` on the GitHub page for `react-testing-library`. Are you working from a particular example?

Comment: Yes. From this one: https://dev.to/iwilsonq/how-to-build-sturdy-react-apps-with-tdd-using-jest-the-react-testing-library-52cn

Comment: What is "this error" and where in all that code does it occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Simulate` has been removed from react-testing-library. What you need to use today is `fireEvent`.

You can use it in this way:

```
import { fireEvent } from 'react-testing-library'

// Then in your test

fireEvent.change(authorNode, { target: { value: newComment.author } })
```

You can read more about `fireEvent` in the [official docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/api-events).

Answer (score -2):

tryed var test = new Simulate(); ?

And then do test.etc....